# Ubuntu 22.04, I just noticed in the settings "Connectivity Checking" should I turn it off? I'm concerned about my privacy

Tags: privacy

I don't want Canonical stealing information from my computer so should I disable it or leave it alone?

Answer (score 4):

Canonical have better things to do than steal your information but it is entirely your choice.

[Connectivity checking](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager/snap-configuration/connectivity-check) is a useful NetworkManager functionality that allows periodically testing whether the system can actually access the internet or not. The network-manager snap allows configuring this feature by using the following snap settings:

```
connectivity.interval : it specifies the number of seconds between checks. If set to 0, it disables connectivity check. Set to 300 by default.
connectivity.response : This is the expected HTTP body response from the server specified by connectivity.uri.
connectivity.uri : The URI where NM is going to periodically access to check connectivity.
```

You can change aspects of the commands which control the way it works - an example is listed in the resource listed above.

Further information about it can be found [here](https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.conf.html)

Further down the list of Privacy options is an option regarding the sending of sending technical problem issues to Canonical which allows you to select *Never, Automatic or Manual*.